# Solve equation containing Mod and Floor functions

Tags: modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

- I have an equation where I am solving for *n*:$$\lfloor x/2^n \rfloor \bmod 2 = 0$$
- The best I can work it is:$$\lfloor x/2^n \rfloor /2 = \lfloor x/(2^n*2) \rfloor$$
- Witch is the same as:$$\lfloor x/2^n \rfloor/2\le x/(2^n*2)\lt\lfloor x/2^n \rfloor/2+1$$
- And I think can be:$$\lfloor x/2^n \rfloor\le x/2^n\lt\lfloor x/2^n \rfloor+2$$
- Another equation that would be easy for me to use is:$$\lfloor a/bc \rfloor \bmod2=0$$
- solving for *b* or *c*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\lfloor x/2^n \rfloor mod 2 = 0$, put $\lfloor x/2^n \rfloor  = 2k$.
Then "open" the floor as
$$
2k \le {x \over {2^{\,n} }} < 2k + 1\quad \left| {\;k \in Z} \right.
$$
where $k$ can be any integer.

However, since $2^n$ is always positive, then, depending on the sign of $x$, we shall have
$$
0 < 2^{\,n} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ {\matrix{
   {k < 0} & {x < 0}  \cr 
   {k = 0} & {x = 0}  \cr 
   {0 < k} & {0 < x}  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$
so that we shall write
$$
2k \le {{\left| x \right|} \over {2^{\,n} }} < 2k + 1\quad \left| {\;0 \le k \in Z} \right.
$$

Therefore, excluding the case $x=0$ for which the solution is indeterminated, we have:
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {2k} \right)2^{\,n}  \le \left| x \right| < \left( {2k + 1} \right)2^{\,n}   \cr 
  & {{\left| x \right|} \over {\left( {2k + 1} \right)}} < 2^{\,n}  \le {{\left| x \right|} \over {\left( {2k} \right)}}  \cr 
  & \ln _2 \left( {\left| x \right|} \right) - \ln _2 \left( {2k + 1} \right) < n \le \ln _2 \left( {\left| x \right|} \right) - \ln _2 \left( {2k} \right)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le k \in Z \hfill \cr 
  \;0 \ne x \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
**Example**

$$
\eqalign{
  & x = 1/2\quad \ln _2 \left( {\left| x \right|} \right) =  - 1  \cr 
  & n \in \left\{ {\left( { - 2.58..,\; - 2} \right],\;\left( { - 3.32..,\; - 3} \right],\;\left( { - 3.807..,\; - 3.58..} \right],\;\left( { - 4.1699..,\; - 4} \right],\; \cdots } \right\} \cr} 
$$
because for instance
$$
\left\lfloor {{{1/2} \over {2^{\, - 2} }}} \right\rfloor  = 2\quad \left\lfloor {{{1/2} \over {2^{\, - 3.7} }}} \right\rfloor  = 6
$$

But if you are looking for integral values of $n$, and the value of $x$ is different from integer powers of $2$,  then the result
gets much more complicated.

Comment: @G Cab, interesting way to put the equation! so, 2k≤x/2^n<2k+1

Comment: Yes, exactly: of course $k$ is any integer (positive or negative).

Comment: So I have posted my answer, but am a little confused with what to replace 2k with.

Comment: does it matter what _k_ is?

Comment: @JohnPorter: yes it matters: $k$ stands for any integer ($k \in \mathbb Z$)

Comment: I no know what that is :(

Comment: @JohnPorter: I expanded my answer, wish it is more clear for you now.

Comment: I like your stuff, but I am not understanding (I would like it more in terms of $\lfloor a/cb \rfloor/2=\lfloor a/2cb\rfloor$ but seems too complicated) and yes n is a whole number (in computer code x|y!==x does close to the same thing)